# What does the idiom, 'bolt from the fold', mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

While reading a novel I've found this expression:

> bolt from the fold

Does anyone know what it means?

Here is the whole sentence to provide some context:

> It is possible that Godfrey found the lifestyle more than a little
>   alienating, for, sometime during the course of his studies at Fargo
>   Congregational College, he bolted from the fold and, to the enduring
>   agony of his parents, fell into worldy pursuits, and ended up,
>   somehow, getting a Ph.D. in Classics from a small private university
>   in Ohio.

Comment: To bolt is to escape.  So the picture is one of the sheep escaping from the pen where the sheep are kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **not an idiom**. The meaning of the expression depends on the meaning of the word "[fold](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fold)" in this context.

Fargo Congregational College sounds like the name of an evangelical Christian college. Its students are most likely the children of people who attend born-again Christian churches. People who want to say nasty things about churchgoers often liken them to sheep. A congregation of sheep is called a "fold". A pen in which sheep are kept is also called a "fold".

So Godfrey left school (bolted) because the lifestyle there alienated him (turned him off; bored him; annoyed him; angered him). He changed his life, changed colleges, and studied something more interesting to him.

Comment: I think the word is often applied to a congregation, for the reasons you state, but not exclusively so. [Here](http://roadsidegeorgia.com/gallery/russell.html) is a good example of the phrase applied to the political arena: _In 1952 Russell announced his candidacy for United State President. In 1948 the "Dixiecrats" had bolted from the fold, unhappy with the direction the Democrats were headed._

Comment: @J.R.: I agree with your comment. I restricted the remark to religious groups because the protagonist of the story the OP referred to seemed to me to be a student at a religious college. Sorry if my answer seemed to say that it was exclusively used for religious groups. As you point out, it's used for any social group, and I suspect that it'd even be used for groups without a stipulated ideology, e.g., a family or a tribe, or a clan.

Comment: It's not just "people who want to say nasty things about churchgoers" who liken congregations to sheep.  Jesus Christ refers to himself as a shepherd and his people as sheep, for example in John 10:14.